# How to start hidden app by using call dialer(keypad) using Android code?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to start my app which is a hidden app by dialing certain predfined number by me programatically ,for eg `*#*#111#*#*`.I open the dialer and input `*#*#111#*#*`.Then My app receives the broadcast and starts.Which broadcast should I listen?

Comment: I don't think that's even possible... Waiting for answers too!

Answer (score 5):

You should input number `*#*#xxxx#*#*`, say, `*#*#110#*#*`.

Create a Receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

public class Listener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String pwd = intent.getData().getHost();

Intent i = new Intent(context, CalllistenerActivity.class);

i.putExtra("data", pwd);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(i);

}

}
```

Create an Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalllistenerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        String pwd = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
        tv.setText(TextUtils.isEmpty(pwd)?"Plz input *#*#123#*#* in dial" :pwd);
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Register in AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".CalllistenerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="Listener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
        <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="110"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You should

Comment: thanks..It works.. :)

Comment: I don't understand where should we put the secret number in the code?

Comment: *#*#8888#*#*.8888 is secret number. You can get it from getIntent().getStringExtra("data").

Comment: should we add android:host in manifest?