# Intercepting number dialed

Tags: android

I don't want to be the default dialer app.

I just want my app to be launched when the users dial a specific number, eg 1234, in the default dialing app.

Is this possible?

Scenario: an airline has an app to make bookings and provide many customer support functions. It also has a customer service hotline. However, it wants to reduce traffic to the hotline (expensive agents) and hopes to see most requests serviced by the app as far as possible. So when a user dials the airline hotline number, the airline app (if installed) is launched instead.

Comment: Why not just make an app? All the major airlines I know of have an app that acts as a boarding pass, and has FAQ information.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858721/how-to-start-hidden-app-by-using-call-dialerkeypad-using-android-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, its possible. Refer to "Listening for outgoing call requests" from [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html).

Run your app on phone load.
Here’s an example broadcast receiver declared in an app’s manifest file:

```
<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />  
<application>
    ...
    <receiver android:name=MyOutgoingCallHandler">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```

The implementation of the corresponding broadcast receiver would look something like this:

```
public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
        String phoneNumber = getResultData();
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
        // No reformatted number, use the original
            phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        }
        // My app will bring up the call, so cancel the broadcast
        setResultData(null);
        // Start my app to bring up the call
    ...
  }
}
```

so you can check the number from

```
phoneNumber
```

Comment: Thanks. Works as advertized!